# How to convert one column's all values to separate column name in DataFrame of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Sample data are as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(2011, 'a', 1.3), (2012, 'a', 1.4), (2013, 'a', 1.6), (2011, 'b', 0.7), (2012, 'b', 0.9), (2013, 'b', 1.2),], columns=['year', 'district', 'price'])
df.set_index(['year'], inplace=True)
df.head(n=10)
```

which could produce data like:

```
    district    price
year        
2011    a       1.3
2012    a       1.4
2013    a       1.6
2011    b       0.7
2012    b       0.9
2013    b       1.2
```

What I intend to convert the DataFrame to is as below:

```
        a       b
year        
2011    1.3     0.7
2012    1.4     0.9
2013    1.6     1.2
```

Could anyone give me some idea on how to do that? Great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pivot

```
In[122]: df.reset_index().pivot('year','district','price')
Out[122]: 
district    a    b
year              
2011      1.3  0.7
2012      1.4  0.9
2013      1.6  1.2
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that really helps!