# How to convert keyword in cell of dataframe to own column each

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
In[8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'transport': ['Car;Bike;Horse','Car','Car;Bike', 'Horse;Car']})
df
Out[8]:
    transport
 0  Car;Bike;Horse
 1  Car
 2  Car;Bike
 3  Horse;Car
```

And I want to convert it to something like this:

```
In[9]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'transport_car': [True,True,True,True],'transport_bike': [True,False,True,False], 'transport_horse': [True,False,False,True]} )
df2
Out[10]:
  transport_bike    transport_car   transport_horse
0   True                True            True
1   False               True            False
2   True                True            False
3   False               True            True
```

I got a solution, but it feels very 'hacked' and 'unpythonic'. (It works for my considerably small data set)

```
In[11]:
# get set of all possible values
new_columns = set()
for element in set(df.transport.unique()):
    for transkey in str(element).split(';'):
        new_columns.add(transkey)
print(new_columns)

# Use broadcast to initialize all columns with default value.
for col in new_columns:
    df['trans_'+str(col).lower()] = False

# Change cells appropiate to keywords
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for key in new_columns:
        if key in row.transport:
            df.set_value(index, 'trans_'+str(key).lower(), True)
df

Out[11]:
    transport     trans_bike    trans_car   trans_horse
0   Car;Bike;Horse  True          True          True
1   Car             False         True          False
2   Car;Bike        True          True          False
3   Horse;Car       False         True          True
```

My goal is to use the second representation to perform some evaluation to answer questions like: "How often is car used?", "How often is car used together with horse", etc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840377/how-to-convert-one-columns-all-values-to-separate-column-name-in-dataframe-of-p/39840429#39840429) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns) answers suggest using `pivot` and `eval` might be the way to go, but I'm not sure.

So what would be the best way, to convert a DataFrame from first representation to the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` and construct a Series for each entry with the splited fields as index. This will result in a data frame with the index as the columns:

```
df.transport.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(True, x.split(";"))).fillna(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer. Might as well finish it off with `pd.concat([df, df.transport.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(True, ['trans_' + col for col in x.split(";")])).fillna(False)], axis=1)`

Comment: In the end, I used Psidorn's answer with the extension from Ted-Petrou.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to extend [the great @Metropolis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41473414/5741205) with a working example:

```
In [249]: %paste
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.transport.str.replace(';',' '))

r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
## -- End pasted text --

In [250]: r
Out[250]:
   bike  car  horse
0     1    1      1
1     0    1      0
2     1    1      0
3     0    1      1
```

now you can join it back to the source DF:

```
In [251]: df.join(r)
Out[251]:
        transport  bike  car  horse
0  Car;Bike;Horse     1    1      1
1             Car     0    1      0
2        Car;Bike     1    1      0
3       Horse;Car     0    1      1
```

**Timing:** for 40K rows DF:

```
In [254]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [255]: df.shape
Out[255]: (40000, 1)

In [256]: %timeit df.transport.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(True, x.split(";"))).fillna(False)
1 loop, best of 3: 33.8 s per loop

In [257]: %%timeit
     ...: vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
     ...: X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.transport.str.replace(';',' '))
     ...: r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
     ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 732 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very clean approach!

Comment: @Metropolis, thank you! I've added timing - `CountVectorizer` is __amazing__! I should have learned it before...

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the [Count Vectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) provided by Scikit-learn. The vectorizer will construct a vector where each index refers to a term and the value refers to the number of appearances of that term in the record.

Advantages over the home-rolled approaches suggested in other answer are efficiency for large datasets and generalizability. Disadvantage is, obviously, bringing in an extra dependency.